# Start of application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have followed the tutorial [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) . I have read that the first file to be execute in my web app is startup.cs, but startup.cs contains only the following code. Which steps happened after the execution of this file? I don't see any page opening... Thank!

```css
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(ContactManager.Startup))]
namespace ContactManager
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml page:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
            ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
            enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
            for enjoyable, agile development.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Startup.cs` will initialize your project by setting up various services. In this case it sets up Authentication framework. Code located in `Startup.cs` runs only once, which is when IIS spins up your site for the first time. It will not run for each subsequent requests.

When you try to open a page, your browser makes a HTTP GET request which will then be intercepted and processed by MVC route management system. Try to locate your route configuration (probably in a file called `RouteConfig.cs`). Your route configuration will give you an indication what view will load by default.

For example; following route tells me, my default view will be what is generated by `Index` method in `HomeController.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thk! So, could you please if I write correctly? RouteConfig.cs -> HomeController.cs -> Home/Index.cshtml.

But, only a question: If I open index.cshtml in my browser I see a complex page (refer to the indicated tutorial) in my browser, with up dynamic menu. And in Index.cshtml I only see html tags <div> for the main contents and not for a dynamic menu. How is it possible? Where is the rest of the code for the page, or how is recalled? (I copy in my original post the complete code of index page).

Comment: In Asp.net MVC, your views are mixed with 'layouts'. The layout would contain look and feel common across the site and your individual views will contain specifics for an area. Look for a file called _layout.cshtml and you will see the code for the rest of the page. Following is a good link about layouts (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp). Hope this helps